# How to enable port 8080 for Xampp?

Tags: xampp, port

```
12:53:58 PM  [Tomcat]   Problem detected!
12:53:58 PM  [Tomcat]   Port 8080 in use by "C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe"!
12:53:58 PM  [Tomcat]   Tomcat WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
12:53:58 PM  [Tomcat]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
12:53:58 PM  [Tomcat]   or reconfigure Tomcat and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

What is httpd.exe, that is preventing from access to 8080 port? I have seen it as console, but why does it need 8080 port?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have installed Apache Tomcat. Maybe it uses the same port?
If yes, stop this Tomcat and restart Xampp .

Steps:

1. Go to control panel-> Administrative tools-> Services and look for Apache.
2. Under the Status tab it says Running.
3. Select it and choose stop.
4. Restart Xampp and check if it works